# Reload rails console with hotkey

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotkeys, irb, rails-console

Is it possible to reload rails console with hotkey? 
Something like binding `reload!` to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> (like reloading page in browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTerm2 you can do smthng like:

Preferences -> Keys -> Global Shortcut Keys -> +

And add following: [image]